# Is there an efficient way of generating numbers with repeated digits in Python?

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to generate all 5 digit numbers out of `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` such that any digit can be repeated at most twice. That is, numbers like `12345, 11267, 11226` are allowed but `11134 or 11115` are not allowed.

I can write a code with multiple for loops perhaps, but I was wondering if there are shorter, more elegant methods available. 
For example, `itertools.product('123456789', repeat=5)` will generate all such 5 tuples (`9^5` in total) or `itertools.permutations(''123456789',5)` will generate all `5` tuples with no repetitions (`9x8x7x6x5` in total). I am wondering is there a way to use these tools to generate all numbers of the form `11235 and 11224` but nothing else without going through multiple for loops and the like.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for StackOverflow than it does for the Data Science StackExchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, just using

```
itertools.permutations('112233445566778899',5)
```

should do the trick.

Edit: that included repeats, since it had two of each digit. Wrapping it in a set seems to solve that:

```
set(itertools.permutations('112233445566778899',5))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your solution. It saved me a lot of unnecessary work.